# Ubuntu KDE on Acer Aspire 7740 - No Brightness fn-key

Tags: kde, brightness, acer, backlight

I have researched this question going back about 8 years and couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Bottom line, the brightness keys do not work on the Aspire 7740 with KDE Plasma. I am sure this has been an annoyance for many owners of the fine laptop if they want to use Linux on it.

If I do

```
$: ls /sys/class/backlight the result is:  
$: video0 acer_wmi intel_backlight
```

So, I added the `acpi_backlight=vendor` kernel parameter to `/etc/default/grub` after the `quiet splash` resulting in `quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor`.

After this, I did

```
sudo update-grub
```

I rebooted into graphical desktop again, reran `ls /sys/class/backlight` and the result was that the video0 was gone leaving acer_wmi and intel_backlight. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> brightness keys still didn't work. So, I blacklisted the acer_wmi module by adding the it to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file:

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

(at the end)
I rebooted again to X, and voilà... the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys work for brightness.

I think this could certainly help any who were frustrated by this (as I was).
Yet, I am not sure of the purpose of the `acer_wmi` module.
Do I need it for something?